# Getting a factor when I prune data based on another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame1 that looks like:

```
          V1
1  rs1000108
2 rs10002573
3 rs10005886
4 rs10006443
5 rs10006845
```

I have another data.frame2 that looks like:

```
          V1
2 rs71509444
3 rs71509445
4 rs71509446
5 rs10006845
6 rs57465118
```

I would like to get rid of any rows in data.frame1 that are in data.frame2. I have been using `dfnew <- df1[(df1$V1 %in% df2$V1),]`. I'm getting an output of a "factor" but I want a "data.frame." How can I do this?

Comment: `df1[(df1$V1 %in% df2$V1),,drop=FALSE]` I presume

Comment: Can you convert your output to a df with `dfnew <- as.data.frame(dfnew)`?